# PostgreSQL 10: is there a scheduler function that can auto refresh a materialized view per interval of time?

Tags: postgresql-10

is there a function in PostgreSQL that allows to refresh a materialized view automatically after every interval of time?

Comment: https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron

Comment: no, you need crontab or extensions

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/maintenance.html

> The tasks discussed here are required, but they are repetitive in
>   nature and can easily be automated using standard tools such as cron
>   scripts or Windows' Task Scheduler. It is the database administrator's
>   responsibility to set up appropriate scripts, and to check that they
>   execute successfully.

Quote tells *not explicitly*, that postgres does **not** has build in scheduler...

You would like to look into [some](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) extensions probably. Or just use cron as docs suggest.